# Website URL validation

Tags: javascript, regex, typescript

I have this code of URL validator,
it passes when typed for example "www.wwww.www" or "wwww.wwwww"
It not passes when dot is added in the end like this "wwww.wwwww.". Need it not pass when we fill in input a value like "wwww.wwwww".  How should I change the code?

```
export class WebsiteValidator {
public static validate(control: AbstractControl) {
const URL_REGEXP = /^(http:\/\/www\.|https:\/\/www\.|http:\/\/|https:\/\/)? 
 [a-z0-9]+([\-\.]{1}[a-z0-9]+)*\.[a-z]{2,5}(:[0-9]{1,5})?(\/.*)?$/;
 return (control.value && !URL_REGEXP.test(control.value)) ? {
    validateUrl: {
      valid: false
    }
  } : null;
 }
}
```

Comment: *wwww.wwwww* may be actually a valid domain name provided someone for some obscure reason registers *wwwww* as TLD or as some local network domain.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you implementing the validator yourself? It's very tricky problem and also a solved one.

Unless you are doing it for fun, I recommend using one of the existing validators like [this one](https://validatejs.org/#validators-url). If you are interested in how it's regex looks, you can find it in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/dperini/729294).

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

try this best code.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('input').keyup(function() {
        var $th = $(this);

        if (isValidUrl($th.val())==1){
            alert("got a valid url!");   
        }else
        {
         alert("got a novalid url!");   
        }

    });
});


function isValidUrl(url){

 var myVariable = url;
    if(/^(http|https|ftp):\/\/[a-z0-9]+([\-\.]{1}[a-z0-9]+)*\.[a-z]{2,5}(:[0-9]{1,5})?(\/.*)?$/i.test(myVariable)) {
      return 1;
    } else {
      return -1;
    }   
}
```